# XSLT / Xalan : calling apply-templates from within a Java extension

Tags: java, xslt, xalan, apply-templates

I am using Xalan and Java for extending a stylesheet.

(Similar example to what I am doing there : [Dictionary example](http://www.developer.com/tech/article.php/629071/Xalan-Extending-XSLT-with-Java.htm))

I struggle to make my tag do an `<xsl:apply-templates/>`. I wish to have this :

```
<xsl:template match="sometag">
    <my-java:tag>
        <xsl:apply-tempates/>
    </my-java:tag>
</xsl:template>
```

My java class containing the method `tag(XSLProcessorContext context, ElemExtensionCall elem)` builds an element `myElem` fed into the context like this :

```
context.outputToResultTree(context.getStylesheet(), myElem);
```

But I wish to apply the templates defined in the stylesheet to subelements of `myElem`.

How can I fire the `<xsl:apply-templates/>` from within my Java class ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xalan I'm doing

```
TransformerImpl transf = context.getTransformer();
for ( int i = fromValue; i <= toValue; i++ )  {
  setInt(variable, i);
  transf.executeChildTemplates(elem, true );
}
```

The idea is to execute a for loop ( the from and to values ) repeating the code inside that x times.  Not sure about the 'true' on the executeChildTemplates though - seems to work.